# iPhone Sensor Data app ploting in Streaming mode

Tags: iphone, python, real-time, accelerometer, sensors

Im using the [Sensor Data app](http://wavefrontlabs.com/Wavefront_Labs/Sensor_Data.html) to access the data from the iPhone's accelerometer. I want to use the steaming option to stream the data to my MacBook in real time. For this I would like some sort of a script that collects this data and plots it in real time.

The makers of the app provide this Python script which sends the data in a string format,

```
import SocketServer

PORTNO = 10552

class handler(SocketServer.DatagramRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        newmsg = self.rfile.readline().rstrip()
        print "Client %s said ``%s''" % (self.client_address[0], newmsg)
        self.wfile.write(self.server.oldmsg)
        self.server.oldmsg = newmsg

s = SocketServer.UDPServer(('',PORTNO), handler)
print "Awaiting UDP messages on port %d" % PORTNO
s.oldmsg = "This is the starting message."
s.serve_forever()`
```

Does anyone know of any scripts out there that do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to gain full control over the plots, you would probably have to install a plotting library in your computer. [Matplotlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/) is an open-source python library that will help you to solve this situation. If you are already familiar with MATLAB programming, this won't be that much different, they even provide an [introduction to Matplotlib for MATLAB](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) users. This will certainly help you plotting things.